# How can I indicate that a parameter in a php function has a type of determined class using the phpDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

In this example:

```
/**
 *
 * @param <type> $foo
 * @return <type> 
 */
function do_something($foo) {
    return $foo->really_do_something();
}
```

How to indicate that $foo must be of the class Foo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/**
 *
 * @param Foo $foo
 * @return <type> 
 */
function do_something(Foo $foo) {
    return $foo->really_do_something();
}
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about the type hinting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

More recent versions of PHP (PHP 5 onwards I think) have parameter types:

```
function do_something(Foo $foo) {
   return $foo->really_do_something();
}
```

Which will throw an exception if $foo is not a type of Foo.

I assume phpDoc picks this up